# render in a controler grails

Tags: grails

I am trying to redirect a user once a controller save action has been made
I am using this which does not seem to work:

```
 render(action:"index", controller:"public" )
```

I am wanting to go to the index action in the public controller. All i get back in the browser is this:

```
 ['action':'index', 'controller':'public']
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out I needed to use redirect instead of render.

```
 redirect(controller: "public", action: "index")
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to write a lot of code yourself. I advice you to look at http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Command%20Line/generate-all.html
So generate some views and a controller and take a look at them. Just to know how grails do it.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling "render" but thinking "redirect".  Render can only go to another view on this controller.  See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html.